# Fetching constraints in SQL database to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

Let's assume I have the following database structure of car manufacturers and the corresponding cars:

**manufacturers:**

```
----------------------------------
| manufacturer | founded_in | id |
|--------------|------------|----|
| Daimler AG   | 1927       | 1  |
| Volkswagen AG| 1937       | 2  |
----------------------------------
```

**cars:**

```
-------------------------------------
| car     | built_in | manufacturer |
|---------|----------|---------------
| C Class | 1993     | 1            |
| E Class | 1993     | 1            |
| Golf    | 1974     | 2            |
-------------------------------------
```

The `id` column of `manufacturers` is the primary key and the `manufacturer` column of `cars` has the corresponding foreign key constraint.

I'd like to produce the following JSON output using PHPs `json_encode`:

```
{
    "manufacturers": {
        "Daimler AG": {
            "founded in": "1927",
            "cars": [
                "C Class",
                "E Class"
            ]
        },
        "Volkswagen AG": {
            "founded in": "1937",
            "cars": [
                "Golf"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

To get the manufacturers and their `founded_in` I'd just perform:

```
SELECT manufacturer, founded_in FROM manufacturers
```

And fetch them to an array. How do I assign the cars correctly though, after making a second query?

Comment: You could do it with a inner join I guess.

Comment: How? I'd need to assign multiple cars to one manufacturer in one join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.7 or higher, you can use the JSON aggregate functions to generate the output you expect directly from a SQL query. I expect that will be more efficient than using php in between.

To start with, consider the following aggregates query, that `JOIN`s both tables and creates a JSON object for each manufacturer, with the list of associated car names in a subarray:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('founded in', m.founded_in, 'cars', JSON_ARRAYAGG(c.car)) js
FROM manufacturers m
INNER JOIN cars c ON c.manufacturer = m.id
GROUP BY m.id, m.founded_in;
```

This returns:

```
| js                                                   |
| ---------------------------------------------------- |
| {"cars": ["C Class", "E Class"], "founded in": 1927} |
| {"cars": ["Golf"], "founded in": 1937}               |
```

To produce the expected output, we can turn this to a subquery and add another level of aggregation:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('manufacturers', JSON_OBJECTAGG(manufacturer, js)) myjson
FROM (
    SELECT 
        m.id, 
        m.manufacturer, 
        JSON_OBJECT('founded in', m.founded_in, 'cars', JSON_ARRAYAGG(c.car)) js
    FROM manufacturers m
    INNER JOIN cars c ON c.manufacturer = m.id
    GROUP BY m.id, m.manufacturer, m.founded_in
) x
```

This yields:

```
| myjson                                                                                                                                           |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
| {"manufacturers": {"Daimler AG": {"cars": ["C Class", "E Class"], "founded in": 1927}, "Volkswagen AG": {"cars": ["Golf"], "founded in": 1937}}} |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2HcQdF9nfgT2ojnerZt54m/0)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can query all the data first

```
SELECT m.manufacturer, m.founded_in
  FROM manufacturers AS m
  JOIN cars AS c ON c.manufacturer_id = m.id
```

and then convert it to your structure in php

```
$manufacturers = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['manufacturer'], $manufacturers)) {
        $manufacturers[$row['manufacturer']] = array(
           'founded_in' => $row['founded_in'],
           'cars' => array());
    }

    array_push($manufactureres[$row['manufacturer']]['cars'], $row['car']);
}
```

There is, for sure, a more functional way of doing this in php but you this should work ...

Comment: So are you suggesting that I should join both tables which have all rows in the manufacturer column filled, even though I only have two? Is that considered good practice?

Comment: Well, it depends on how much data do you have. You can have two separate queries too, and fill the same structure.

Comment: As a practice you could say, let the database handle it all, since its made for stuff like that. If it costs too much, you could fill bogus values into a test database and run a benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an object relational mapper like [Respect/Relational](http://respect.github.io/Relational/)

You would be able to simply call:

```
use Respect\Relational\Mapper;

$mapper  = new Mapper(new PDO($db_string, $db_user, $db_pass));
$results = $mapper->manufacturers->cars->fetchAll();
$json    = json_encode($results);
```

Leave the heavy lifting to the API.